# upload a folder to git via powershell while maintaining folder structure

Tags: powershell, github-api

I am trying to write a script that uploads a folder to GitHub while preserving its directory structure. Instead of uploading the folder's files to a single repository, I want to create new repositories for each subdirectory within the main folder. This way, the entire folder structure will remain the same, and I won't need to install any additional software on my device.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
# Define your GitHub username, repository name, and PAT (Personal Access Token)
$username = "username"
$repository = "repos"
$pat = "PAT"

# Define the folder you want to upload and its path
$folderPath = "H:\Add Take Ownership Option in Context Menu"

# Function to upload a folder and its contents recursively
function Upload-Folder {
    param (
        [string]$folderPath,
        [string]$baseRepository
    )

    # Get all items (files and directories) in the folder
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
            # Calculate the relative file path within the folder
            $relativePath = $item.FullName.Substring($folderPath.Length)

            # Normalize path separators and remove leading slash
            $relativePath = $relativePath -replace '\\', '/' -replace '^/', ''

            # Create a JSON request body to create a directory
            $body = @{
                message = "Create directory via PowerShell"
                content = $null
                type = "dir"
            }

            # Create the URL for the API request using the relative file path
            $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$username/$repository/contents/$baseRepository/$relativePath"

            # Send the API request to create a directory
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
                Authorization = "token $pat"
            } -Method PUT -ContentType "application/vnd.github.v3+json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)

            Write-Host "Directory created: $baseRepository/$relativePath"

            # Recursively upload the contents of the subfolder
            Upload-Folder -folderPath $item.FullName -baseRepository "$baseRepository/$relativePath"
        } else {
            # Read the file content as a byte array
            $fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($item.FullName)

            # Encode the file content as Base64
            $base64Content = [Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContent)

            # Calculate the relative file path within the folder
            $relativePath = $item.FullName.Substring($folderPath.Length)

            # Normalize path separators and remove leading slash
            $relativePath = $relativePath -replace '\\', '/' -replace '^/', ''

            # Create a JSON request body to upload a file
            $body = @{
                message = "Upload file via PowerShell"
                content = $base64Content
            }

            # Create the URL for the API request using the relative file path
            $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$username/$repository/contents/$baseRepository/$relativePath"

            # Send the API request to create or update the file
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
                Authorization = "token $pat"
            } -Method PUT -ContentType "application/vnd.github.v3+json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)

            Write-Host "File uploaded successfully: $baseRepository/$relativePath"
        }
    }
}

# Upload the main folder and its contents
Upload-Folder -folderPath $folderPath -baseRepository ""
```

i am encountering this error when running the script

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"path cannot start with a
slash","errors":[{"resource":"Commit","field":"path","code":"invalid"}],"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents"}
At line:60 char:13
+             Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```